# Is it possible to determine if a string is anywhere in a string array in one line?

Tags: c#, string, loops

I've got this looping code to determine if a string exists anywhere in a string array:

```
private bool OneOfTheAustralianWords(string _whirred)
{
    string[] australian100 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\PlatypiRUs.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
    foreach (string whirred in australian100)
    {
        if (whirred.Trim().ToUpper() == _whirred.Trim().ToUpper()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there a simpler/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Efficiency is a tricky thing. If the file is small, reading it all in memory in one go is most efficient. If it's large, you'll want to process it in pieces, otherwise you run out of RAM and start swapping. The most performant way might be memory mapped files, but that's tricky to do in C#, and also for this task in particular. The code would get very complicated fast, so it's only worth considering if you're after every last bit of performance possible (the  again, you might want to consider C++ in that case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
return File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\PlatypiRUs.txt", Encoding.UTF8)
    .Any(l => l.Trim().ToUpper() == _whirred.Trim().ToUpper());
```

Also still I would recommend introducing variable for `_whirred.Trim().ToUpper()` and using [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_) which returns enumerable (as suggested  by [yaakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1994390/yaakov)) and using `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` not to uppercase the string from the file:

```
var searched = _whirred.Trim();
return File.ReadLines(@"C:\PlatypiRUs.txt", Encoding.UTF8)
        .Any(l => l.Trim().Equals(searched, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `File.ReadLines` be more efficient than `File.ReadAllLines`?

Comment: Simpler? Yes. More efficient? Not really. You could at least trim `_whirred` before the start, rather than redoing it for every line. Also try using case insensitive string comparison rather than `ToUpper`. Not only will that be more correct (the `ToUpper` trick doesn't work in some languages), but also avoid creating extra temporary strings.

Comment: For the second version: you don't need to convert `whirred` to uppercase.

Comment: @Vilx- agreed. Forgot to remove.